# Where can I see red tubes instead of green ones in Flappy Bird?

Tags: flappy-bird

I decompiled the Flappy Bird android APK a couple days ago, and after while, I've noticed something strange.

The gfx base image, which contains all the sprites and other stuff. Also have a red tube, but I never saw any of this thing (only hacks and fake videos).

**Where do these red tubes appear?**

**EDIT:** I also, did't notice before posting here that the red tube, have two up variations, and no down one.

[image: Flappy Bird decompiled graphics]

Comment: And what is the question here?

Comment: Where it appears?

Comment: @Jupotter Editted :)

Comment: The title is misleading for birds looking for action.

Comment: Sorry, just typed the way it came in mind...

Answer (score 5):

They do not seem to appear in the game.

The **atlas.txt** file that names the sections of the tileset (**altlas.png**). This text file refers to the red pipes in the tileset as **pipe2_down** and **pipe2_up** respectively.

They only seem to appear in version 1.2.

I have not checked the iOS version.

**Source:**
Me extracting the apk of Flappy Bird 1.2